# Mais de um tipo de layout em um ContentPage

Tags: mobile, xamarin

É possível ter mais de uma Tipo de layout, dentro de um ContentPage?

Estou desenvolvendo um app,e ele precisa de uma barra superior com alguns botões e uma listagem de Nomes.

Como pode ser feito?